# How Do I Calculate the profit of the value of my bitcoin?

Tags: exchange-rate, price-volatility, price-discovery

Lets say I buy $50 of a bitcoin for 3916.74, And then the price goes up to $4200. How Do I calculate how much I have made in profit?
As in What type of formula do I use to see how much more my $50 is worth now that the price is higher than when I bought it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a basic math question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to calculate would be:

`averagecost = ((BTC[t0] x USD[t0]) + (BTC[t1] x USD[t1]) + (so on))/total_BTC`

where `t0`,`t1` and so on are different time when you bought.

The above gives you the average cost for all your BTC

Now to know the profit, use the below formula:

`profitloss = (current_BTC_price - averagecost) x total_BTC`

If `profitloss` is negative, then you have a loss.

If `profitloss` is positive, then you have a profit.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, let a number of bitcoins be bought and **(x1)** is how much you paid for it.
2. Now the price of 1 bitcoin changes
3. Then you use the formula:

   **x2= (New value of 1 bitcoin)*(Number of bitcoins you have)**

Now you just find the difference between **x1** and **x2**. This will give you your profit/loss.

All you have to remember is the initial value. In your case it is 50.

Therefore,

**x1**=50

your bitcoins, in this case, = 50/3916.74 ~ 0.0128

**x2**= 4200*0.0128
      =  53.76

so your profit **x2-x1**= **3.76** is your profit

Comment: Be a lot nicer of someone could break this down simpler than the two answers shown, For example.. let’s say you buy $50 at $7500, and the price goes to $9000. What’s the profit margin? Should be $1500 right? That seems pretty simple.

Comment: But instead, it’s like $63 or something. Would love a formula that isn’t as ridiculous as the ones posted above.

Comment: @ElSols: No, $53.76 is correct. The profit margin is not the increase in the exchange rate, but the increase in the value of your own holdings.